# How to get an Ubuntu 18.04 server to automatically reconnect to network after reboot?

Tags: networking, 18.04, reboot, netplan

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 server running on my home network. On reboot, it does not automatically connect to the network. I have the `netplan` yaml file correctly configured for dhcp connection. By googling around, I found this solution:

Enter this manually after reboot:

```
   sudo ip link set dev <name of my ethernet interface> up
   sudo dhclient -v <name of my ethernet interface>
```

Once I do that, the server connects to the network. But on every reboot, I have to repeat this procedure, which of course makes it impossible to reboot the server while not being able to access it physically.

I do not really know what the two lines above do, and am looking for a method that will auto connect to the network even after a remote reboot.

Answer (score 1):

This solved it:

> you've probably confused the netplan calendaring tool with netplan the
>   network configuration tool install netplan.io not netplan

```
(sudo) apt install netplan.io netplan-
```

Comment: Why was the netplan.io package not installed on your system? It is installed by default on all Ubuntu 18.04 systems.